# Removing Try failures in collection using flatMap

Tags: scala

I have a Map[String, String]

How can I simply this expression using flatMap?

```
 val carNumbers = carMap.keys.map(k => Try(k.stripPrefix("car_number_").toInt)).toList.filter(_.isSuccess)
```

Note: I want to remove the Failure/Success wrapper and just have a List[Int].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to convert `Try` to `Option`:

```
for {
  key <- carMap.keys
  t <- Try(key.stripPrefix("car_number_").toInt).toOption
} yield t
```

this will result `Iterable` and you can convert it to list with `.toList` method.

Also you can go with oneliner like this:

```
carMap.keys.flatMap(k => Try(k.stripPrefix("car_number_").toInt).toOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `collect()` with a partial function:

```
carMap.keys
    .collect( k => 
      Try(k.stripPrefix("car_number_").toInt) match { 
        case Success(num) => num
        }
    )
```

This will return an `Iterable[Int]` with the values that could be stripped and converted to an `Int` (assuming this is what you were looking for).